# .net core IActionResult returns base class instead of derived class

Tags: c#, .net-core, polymorphism

I have a .Net core project using mongodb. I have a derived class and a base class. In my controller, I'm trying to return a list of the derived class to Ok(), but when I view the response, I'm getting a list of the base class being returned.

```cs
    [Route("albums")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAllAlbums()
    {
        List<AlbumAdd> albums = (List<AlbumAdd>) _repo.GetAll<AlbumAdd>("albums");

        return Ok(albums); 
    }
```

When I breakpoint, the albums list is the derived class so it's just when sending the Ok response that they're being sent as base class. Not sure if this has anything to do with mongo mapping, but here are my DTOs.

```cs
[DataContract]
public class AlbumAdd : AlbumBase
{
    [BsonElement("rating")]
    [DataMember]
    public double Rating;

    [BsonElement("addDate")]
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime AddDate;

    [BsonElement("format")]
    [DataMember]
    public List<AlbumFormat> Format;

}
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(AlbumAdd))]
[DataContract]
public class AlbumBase
{
    [BsonId]
    [DataMember]
    public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]    
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("title")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("artists")]
    public string[] Artists { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("genres")]
    public string[] Genres { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public AlbumType Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [BsonElement("year")]
    public int ReleaseYear;
}
```

Help appreciated thanks.

Comment: How do you verify if it is base class objects?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya When i make the http request to my endpoint /albums , the response is a list of the base class, but i wanted a list of the derived class

Comment: Are you getting json response from the API? Are you not getting derived class properties in json? Can you share the code which makes the http request and checks the response?

Comment: How did you resolved it?